# how to send ajax request in jQuery with data encoded

Tags: jquery

when i send ajax request i got the error that

```
 $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: furl2,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                        data: { id: id, url: $("#id" + id + " .customURL").val() },
                        success: function (msg) {
                          //some code here
                        },
                    });
                }
```

i got the error that id is undefined even i put them.

how i can send a ajax request to server using ajax.

Comment: I don't see `id` defined, `id: id` is looking for a variable named `id`...where is that?

Comment: i define them and they worked i try in firebug.

Comment: @steven - You need to *show* where you define them, you're question is entirely based around code you're not showing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// create an empty object
var data = {};

// create and populate nodes in the object
data.id = id;
data.url = //what ever you wanted it to be

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: furl2,
      cache: false,
      dataType: "json",
      data: data, // send the object to the server as post data
       success: function (result) {
           // try and grab a node in the json object
           console.log(result.foo);
       },
});
```

This will send the data as posts to the server, and require json encoded data in return, which is nice becasue you don't have to send the html from the server, you can just construct it in the js.

If you wanna encode data from the server with for example php you can do it on a regular array or object

```
<?php 
    // fetch what ever post we need
    $id = $_POST['id'];

    $arr = array(
          "foo" => "1", 
          "two" => "2"
    );

    return json_encode($arr);

?>
```

Comment: No problem, I hope this solves your problem, otherwise just pm me or something and I'll explain even further. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

In JSON it's

```
String : value
```

Try adding quotes around your field names, e.g.

```
{
  "type": "POST", 
  "url": furl2, 
  "something": "else",
  "fortytwo": 42
}
```

Edit: There's a comma after your success function that seems to do nothing. Have you checked that?

Comment: after using this i found they never send the inforamation i want preharps they send blank request.